# navigation.goBack not working in react native

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

This is the structure of my project: Tab navigator has two screens DailyTab and WeeklyTab. DailyTab is itself a stack navigator which has two screens Daily and Todos. Daily is the default screen and I am able to navigate from Daily to Todos but the same Todos screen appears when I press the back button on Todos(I expect it to take me to Daily screen)

Main:

```
const Main = () => {
  const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

  return (
    <NavigationContainer independent={true}>
      <Tab.Navigator>
        <Tab.Screen
          name="DailyTab"
          component={DailyTab}
        />
        <Tab.Screen
          name="WeeklyTab"
          component={WeeklyTab}
        />
        
      </Tab.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
};
```

DailyTab:

```
const DailyTab = () => {

  return (
    <NavigationContainer independent={true}>
      <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Daily">
        <Stack.Screen
          name="Daily"
          component={Daily}
          options={{headerShown: false}}
        />
        <Stack.Screen
          name="Todos"
          component={Todos}
          options={{headerShown: false}}
        />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
};

const Daily = ({navigation}) => {
  return (
    <View style={globalStyles.overallBackground}>
      <Navbar />
      <Calendar navigation={navigation} />
    </View>
  );
};
```

Todos:

```
const Todos = ({route, navigation}) => {
  return (
    <View style={globalStyles.overallBackground}>
      <Navbar />
      <Button title="back" onPress={()=>navigation.goBack()} ></Button>
    </View>
  );
};
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: how are you navigating from Daily to Todos? Maybe it's navigating twice or something like that

Answer (score 0):

Try out putting --

```
this.props.navigation.goBack()
```

Comment: I am using a functional component not a class component